# How to fix this price quote JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

How would I get the totals of 3 tables into one?

I am calculating a price for something and I am trying to get it to where
total4=(total1*total2)+total3 +n. N is a number that will equal to 275 if total1 >160. Right now the numbers for the tables are multiplying randomly.

```
    var gt = null;
    var gt2 = null;
    var gt3 = null;
     

    gt = 0;
    gt2 = 0;
    gt3 = 0;

calc(){
grandTot.textContent = gt.toFixed(2);
grandTot2.textContent = gt2.toFixed(2);
grandTot3.textContent = gt3.toFixed(2);
var gt4 = null;
    gt4 = 0;
    var n= 0;
    gt4= ((gt*gt2)+gt3) +n ;

    if(a>160){
      n=275;
    } else{
      n=0;
    }


    
    grandTot4.textContent = gt4.toFixed(2);

    }
```

Comment: If you need more of the code please let me know I had to cut out a huge chunk to post this question!

Comment: What is a,b and c variable? Is it defined?

Comment: I suppose it should be: `gt4= ((gt1*gt2)+gt3) +n;` and `if(gt1>160){n=275;}else{n=0;}`. Additionally I think the if-statement should be before gt4=... .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using n before setting it to the value that you want. Assuming that you want n to depend on gt, it should look like this. I cleaned up some of the declaration.

```
let gt = 0;
let gt2 = 0;
let gt3 = 0;

calc(){
    grandTot.textContent = gt.toFixed(2);
    grandTot2.textContent = gt2.toFixed(2);
    grandTot3.textContent = gt3.toFixed(2);
    let gt4 = 0;
    let n = 0;

    if(gt>160){
      n=275;
    } else{
      n=0;
    }

    gt4= ((gt*gt2)+gt3) +n ;
    grandTot4.textContent = gt4.toFixed(2);
}
```